# How to vertical center floated div with anchor and image

Tags: css, center, vertical-alignment

I want to center my images inside a div that is floated. I've tried `vertical-align:middle;` but that wasn't a success. I guess that's because it's floated.

I've created a jfiddle about my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/au0h6u0g/

Comment: you could use line-height and vertical-align on img https://jsfiddle.net/au0h6u0g/4/ or , display:table, inline-block, flex even transform ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks, your solution is probably the cleanest and easiest. I suggest you to submit it as answer, so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: okay, added comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `vertical-align` on `img` and `line-height`, example:

```css
.top {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  float: right;
  line-height: 150px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Smiley face" height="50" width="140">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/au0h6u0g/4/

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look to make it center

```
  .container
{
  float:right;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
}

.container img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that container has to be float:right;

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display:table;` for `.top` and `display:table-cell;` with `vertical-align:middle;` with `.container`

```css
.top
{
  width:100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color:blue;
  display:table;
  direction:rtl;
}

.container
{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Smiley face" height="50"     width="140">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

To `.top`, add the declarations:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
```

To the `.container`, add:

```
flex: auto 1 0;
```

And finally, move the `float: right` declaration to the `image` rather than the container.

See the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snowguy13/au0h6u0g/1/).

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/au0h6u0g/5/

You can use absolute positioning and translate for offsett based on element size.

```
<div class="top">
  <div class="container">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Smiley face" height="50"     width="140">
  </div>
</div>

.top
{
  height: 150px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.container
{
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
}

.container img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell form the number of answers, there are *many* ways to do this. Here's another which requires you to position the `img` absolutely at 0px on each axis and then use `margin:0` to center it:

```css
.top {
  height: 150px;
  background-color:blue;
  position:relative;
}

.container img {
  float:right;/* < this is redundant but you said that you must have it.*/
  position:absolute;
  top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Smiley face" height="50" width="140">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```